# A mapper_parsing_exception occurred when using the bulk API of Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

Elasticsearch version: 8.3.3

Indexing was performed using the following Elasticsearch API.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/bulk_meta/_doc/_bulk?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' 
{"index": { "_id": "1"}}
{"mydoc": "index action, id 1 "}
{"index": {}}
{"mydoc": "index action, id 2"}
'
```

In this case, the following error occurred.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Malformed content, found extra data after parsing: START_OBJECT"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I've seen posts asking to add \n, but that didn't help.

Comment: Where's the closing single quote in your bulk call?

Comment: val/ sorry. modified

Comment: Weird, the same call works ok on my test cluster

Comment: @john_smith please check after removing `_doc` from url as i mentioned in below answer.

Comment: @Sagar Patel Thx. It worked!! Is it a version problem or what kind of problem?

Comment: I think so yes. because in 8.x version document type is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `_doc` from the requst.

```json
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/bulk_meta/_bulk?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"mydoc":"index action, id 1 "}
{"index":{}}
{"mydoc":"index action, id 2"}
'
```

Comment: In another document, it was said to include the type, but is the reason why it was omitted because of the version?

Comment: Can you provide document link. as far as i know, it is because of version change as 8.x type is removed.